# Scroll to line in Monaco editor

Tags: javascript, typescript, monaco-editor

I see there is a way to set `scrolltop` in monaco editor. How would one scroll to a specific line instead of a specific pixel?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

As in the docs: https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/api/interfaces/monaco.editor.icodeeditor.html

Scroll to top, in px:

```
editor.setScrollPosition({scrollTop: 0});
```

Scroll to a specific line:

```
editor.revealLine(15);
```

Scroll to a specific line so it ends in the center of the editor:

```
editor.revealLineInCenter(15);
```

Move current active line:

```
editor.setPosition({column: 1, lineNumber: 3});
```

Answer (score 6):

I just want to add that if you want to scroll to the last line, you can use

```
editor.revealLine(editor.getModel().getLineCount())
```